# How to dynamically configure rampart on service side

Tags: web-services

how can i dynamically configure rampart on the service side? I mean I'd like to use different service keys for different clients.

Any hint or link to a tutorial is a big help.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you want the ability to issue a different token depending on the client credentials?  This sounds a lot like Security Token Service (STS)

It is possible to accept a range of credential options. Rampart makes you implement your own callback class to verify the initial credentials.

You can implement your own TokenIssuer to customize the response (http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/setting-up-sts.html)  and either bundle that inside your service archive or externalize it.  You can use whatever criteria is fit for determining the responsetoken.